# Как из функции vk.method("photos.getMessagesUploadServer") после выполнения, вытащить значение upload_url и засунуть его в переменную upload_photo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Нужно чтобы в цикле при получении фото от пользователя, его url сохранялся в переменной upload_photo

```
while True:
    messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset" : 0, "count" : 20, "filter" : "unanswered"})
    print(vk.method("photos.getMessagesUploadServer"))
```

Comment: приложите код путём правки своего вопроса

Comment: я просто ради теста его пытался хотя бы вывести, чтобы потом уже понять как его записать в переменную

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример на коленке:

```
data = vk.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(user_id=target_id)

upload_url = data["upload_url"]
files = {'photo': open("hello.jpg", 'rb')}

response = requests.post(upload_url, files=files)
result = json.loads(response.text)
```